# Download CSV file to user-defined path

Tags: c#, csv, dialog, save, download

I'm trying to get a Save dialog box to pop-up and prompt the user what location they would like to save a particular file to after they hit an API route.  However, i can't seem to get it to pop-up even though i can generate my CSV file, no problems! UPDATE: i can get the prompt to save to pop-up with the code below but ONLY for my API project.  Whenever i get to the same API route, but go through my TypeScripted front-end UI i can't get the same prompt to pop-up.  What's the deal?

```
                String FileName = "myTestSampleName.csv";
            String FilePath = @"C:\Users\myUser\Documents\myFile.csv";
            HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
            response.ClearContent();
            response.Clear();
            response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName + ";");
            response.TransmitFile(FilePath);
            response.Flush();
            response.End();
```

Comment: When you go through the browser directly, it interprets the `Content-Disposition` header automatically and prompts you to save the file (by design). When you go through your Type Script it bypasses the browser as you are making a direct call to the API. So you're going to have to write some code to launch a save dialog yourself from the front-end UI

Comment: Really? Okay, i'll get on-board w/ that!